# Can I use the BF-888S programming cable on the UV-5R?

Tags: baofeng, radio-programming

I have a Baofeng UV-5R, but no USB programming cable. I also have a Baofeng BF-888S with a USB cable. Is it safe to use the 888S cable on the UV5R?

I was able to find a [cable description on the Baofeng site](https://baofengtech.com/pccable), but it does not list the compatible models.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's compatible.

According to [baofengradio.us](https://baofengradio.us/baofeng-ftdi-usb-cable.html), the compatible models are

> - UV-5R and UV-5R V2+
> - BF-F8+ and BF-F9 V2+
> - UV-82 and UV-82 V2+
> - BF-888S and the ATR-22
> - 997-S

With that information, I have connected the UV-5R and I was able to use the Chirp software with it.